# Sql server certification exam

Tags: sql-server

I am interested in taking sql server certification exams. I do not know where and how to go about it. I want to know the phases involved, server version, price, and the right course materials to aid me in the exam.

Comment: Your question is not well suited for Stack Overflow's format.  This forum is for specific programming questions.  You might want to try posting/researching the MSDN forums, or maybe Quora.

Answer (score 3):

welcome to stackoverflow. I suggest you change your query to the MSDN forum

You can find information here [MCSA - SQL Certification](https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/learning/mcsa-sql-certification.aspx)

the exams to complete the MCSA certification: SQL Server consists of three exams.

- Querying Microsoft SQL Server 2012/2014
- Administering Microsoft SQL Server 2012/2014 Databases
- Implementing Data Warehouse with Microsoft SQL Server 2012/2014

each with an approximate value of 80 USD. resources for study you have many from books to tutorials, in [edx.org](https://www.edx.org/) there are courses that guide you to these certifications